# Android moving Image view to center of the screen

Tags: android, image, view, translate-animation

I have one button and one image view at the bottom of my screen . when the button is clicked i want to move the image view to center of my screen. i'm trying with the following code . i'm not getting correctly. please help me.

my.java file

```
      button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        float   x=metrics.heightPixels/2;
        float   y=metrics.widthPixels/2;
         TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, x , 0, y);
         anim.setDuration(1000);
         anim.setFillAfter( true );
          imageview.startAnimation(anim);

        }
    });
```

Comment: which layout use in .xml file?(Relative or Linear)

Answer (score 4):

**Without Animations**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
                     parms2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                     parms2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                      imageview.setLayoutParams(parms2);

                }
            });
```

OR
**Edit**
**With Animated**

```
RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.rl1 );
                DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
               // this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
                int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - root.getMeasuredHeight();

                int originalPos[] = new int[2];
                imageview.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

                int xDest = dm.widthPixels/2;
                xDest -= (img.getMeasuredWidth()/2);
                int yDest = dm.heightPixels/2 - (imageview.getMeasuredHeight()/2) - statusBarOffset;

                TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );
                anim.setDuration(1000);
                anim.setFillAfter( true );
                imageview.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Thanks you all for their replies. how can i move the image view to center with Translate animation.?

Answer (score 0):

Do this on Button click:

```
LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: why it's not moving with Translate animation?

Answer (score -1):

Your layout file code would be better to debug. Anyways i am assuming you are using a Relative Laytout as a parent for the button and image as it would be easier to do it.